# Fun with casting and inheritance

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, inheritance, casting

NOTE: This question is written in a C# like pseudo code, but I am really going to ask which languages have a solution.  Please don't get hung up on syntax.

Say I have two classes:

```
 class AngleLabel: CustomLabel
 {
     public bool Bold;  // Just upping the visibility to public
     // code to allow the label to be on an angle
 }

 class Label: CustomLabel
 {
     public bool Bold;  // Just upping the visibility to public
     // Code for a normal label
     // Maybe has code not in an AngleLabel (align for example).
 }
```

They both decend from this class:

```
 class CustomLabel
 {
     protected bool Bold;
 }
```

The bold field is exposed as public in the descended classes.

No interfaces are available on the classes.

Now, I have a method that I want to beable to pass in a CustomLabel and set the Bold property.  Can this be done without having to 1) find out what the real class of the object is and 2) cast to that object and then 3) make seperate code for each variable of each label type to set bold.  Kind of like this:

```
 public void SetBold(customLabel: CustomLabel)
 {
     AngleLabel angleLabel;
     NormalLabel normalLabel;


     if (angleLabel is AngleLabel )
     {
        angleLabel= customLabel as AngleLabel 
        angleLabel.Bold = true;
     }

     if (label is Label)
     {
        normalLabel = customLabel as Label
        normalLabel .Bold = true;
     }
 }
```

It would be nice to maybe make one cast and and then set bold on one variable.

What I was musing about was to make a fourth class that just exposes the bold variable and cast my custom label to that class.

Would that work?

If so, which languages would it work for?  (This example is drawn from an old version of Delphi (Delphi 5)).  I don't know if it would work for that language, (I still need to try it out) but I am curious if it would work for C++, C# or Java.

If not, any ideas on what would work?  (Remember no interfaces are provided and I can not modify the classes.)

Any one have a guess?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Couldn't `AngleLabel` and `Label` live off `Control`'s `bold` flag? Why do they have to have their own? (And if `Control.bold` isn't relevant to the question, why show it?)

Comment: @sbi -  sorry for the confusion, I will remove the control reference.  As I said, this example is drawn from Delphi.  The control class in Delphi does not have a bold property.

Comment: @~mathepic - the example method show is actually larger than just setting the bold value.  (I simplified it.)  In the larger method, I have many redundant lines that are setting the same values, but for either AngeleLabel or Label.  I would like to reduce the risk of maintenance messing that up by only making a change in one spot.

Comment: You're drawing some confusion because it looks like your descendant classes are declaring *their own* `bold` fields when in fact you just want to illustrate that they're merely changing the access to the field inherited from the ancestor class.

Comment: In Java, the descendant classes are in fact hiding the superclass's field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would work in Delphi. Code in the same unit as the classes it uses have implicit access to protected (but not strict protected) members, even those members declared in another unit. You'de declare the property protected in `CustomLabel`:

```
type
  CustomLabel = class
  private
    FBold: Boolean;
  protected
    property Bold: Boolean read FBold write FBold;
  end;
```

The bold-setting procedure, in another unit, would have its own `CustomLabel` descendant:

```
type
  TAccessCustomLabel = class(CustomLabel);

procedure SetBold(customLabel: CustomLabel)
begin
  TAccessCustomLabel(customLabel).Bold := True;
end;
```

You can't use an `as` cast on that because the actual parameter will never be an instance of `TAccessLabel`. It will be an instance of `AngleLabel` or `NormalLabel`, but since the portions inherited from `CustomLabel` by all three classes are common, the `Bold` property is the same in all of them. That remains true even after the property has been publicized or published in a descendant:

```
type
  AngleLabel = class(CustomLabel)
  public
    property Bold;
  end;
```

You can change the visibility of properties, but not fields. If you try the same thing with a field, you'll be declaring a *new* field with the same name that hides the inherited field.

---

You can do something similar in C++, but it's not as commonly done as it is in Delphi, so it's likely to draw some ire, especially if you intend to write portable code.

Declare a fourth class, like in Delphi. C++ isn't as loose with member access as Delphi is, but it has the concept of *friendship*, which works just as well in this case.

```
class AccessCustomLabel: public CustomLabel
{
  friend void SetLabel(CustomLabel* customLabel);
};
```

That function now has full access to the class's members:

```
void SetLabel(CustomLabel* customLabel)
{
  // Not allowed:
  // customLabel->bold = true

  // Not ordinarily allowed; requires friendship
  reinterpret_cast<AccessCustomLabel*>(customLabel)->bold = true;
}
```

That's technically *undefined behavior* because we've type-casted an object to a type that it doesn't really have. We're relying on all descendants of `CustomLabel` to have the same layout, in particular for the `bold` member of an `AccessCustomLabel` to reside at the same relative position as the `bold` member of any other `CustomLabel` descendant.

---

The type casting in the Delphi and C++ code performs *type punning*. You're not going to get away with that in C# or Java; they check the results of their casts, so if `customLabel` doesn't really hold an instance of `AccessCustomLabel`, you'll get an exception. You'll have to use reflection to access the protected members of unrelated classes in those languages. Demonstrating that is beyond my depth.

Comment: Indeed they are properties, so this should work great.  I will give it a try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since the parent is protected the answer is that it should not work in any language without additional work, unless the code in question is performed in a descendant of the custom version.

Delphi has an option to use a [protected hack](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/l/aa082603a.htm) to make it work.   C# and Java could use reflection.  C++ friends could be used to make it work.

But if you had declared Bold as Public in the CustomLabel, then the functionality would work in all of the languages you have specified.  Delphi, C++, C#, and Java with out having to do anything special.

Answer (score 1):

C++ would solve this with a template (assuming `SetBold` is the equivalent of `Bold` in your sample):

```
template<typename T> void SetBold(T t) {
    t.SetBold();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really work in the given use case. In C++ syntax, the input parameter is `CustomLabel* customLabel`. Templates do compile-time polymorphism, but to do it, you need to know the actual type at compile time, meaning you can't escape the code that checks for every known descendant of `CustomLabel` and accesses the class-specific `Bold` member. Templates let you escape implementing `SetBold` for every individual class, but it doesn't help with the dispatching.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Delphi 2005 or later, you could use class helpers. Class helpers can access protected fields and methods of the "helped" class. Something similar may be possible with C# extension methods, but that isn't an area I'm that familiar with.

Note: I have been unable to test this as I don't have a compiler handy.

```
type
   TLabelHelper = class helper for CustomLabel
   public 
     procedure SetBolded(ABold : Boolean);
   end;

procedure TLabelHelper.SetBolded(ABold : Boolean);
begin
  Bold := ABold;
end;
```

...

```
Label.SetBolded(True);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# 3.0 and higher you can use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx); those are similar to the [Delphi Class Helpers](http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/delphi-class-helper-to-add-for-%E2%80%A6-in-support-for-tcomponentcomponentscomponentcount/) that [Gerry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22545/gerry) mentioned.

It goes along these lines (watch the `this` keyword).

```
public static class CustomLabelExtensions // name here is not important, just make it readable
{
    public static void SetBolded(this CustomLabel customLabel, bool newValue)
    {
        customLabel.Bold = newValue;
    }
}
```

Note I left out the namespace like you did in your pseudo code.
Make sure however that CustomLabelExtensions is visible to your code, either by using its' namespace or by explicitly specifying that namespace.

Also note that Extension Methods only allow you to add methods, not properties (coming from a Delphi background, that was odd to me).

You then use the above code like this:

```
AngleLabel angleLabel;
NormalLabel normalLabel;
// some code that assigns values to the variables
angleLabel.SetBolded(true);
normalLabel.SetBolded(true);
```

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a mid class (named for example CCC) between CustomLabel and the other two classes.

```
public class CCC : CustomLabel
```

This class should has a function named SetBold(bool bold) that will set the protected field.

```
public void SetBold(bool bold)
{
    base.Bold = bold;
}
```

AngleLabel and Label will both inherit CCC

and the parameter for SetBold(...) will be of type CCC

Comment: Alas, as I alluded to toward the end of my question.  I cannot change the AngleLabel or Label classes.